# TikZ ignores temporary overridden macro value and uses the previous one

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, pgfkeys

I'm racking my brains with the strange behaviour of this simple TikZ graphic:

I have the following pgf keys:

```
\tikzset{
    the name/.store in=\nodename,
    the name=OLD,
    my node/.style={
        node contents=\nodename,
        other node=\nodename,
    },
    other node/.style={
        append after command={
            \pgfextra
            \node [base right=of \tikzlastnode] {#1};
            \endpgfextra
        }
    }
}
```

then I create a node overriding the `\nodename` by setting `the name=NEW`:

```
\node (node 1) [
    the name=NEW, % temporary overrides the node name
    my node       % draw the nodes using the value stored in \nodename 
];
```

This should be the expected result:

[image: expected result]

However this is what I have:

[image: actual result]

How can I achieve the desired result?

Arised questions:

- Is the style code saved as it and then evaluated everytime its instantiated?
- Does TikZ peform any kind of custom magic when the `append after command` style appears?
- It would be any difference by using `\pgfkeysvalueof` instead of save the value in a macro?

Thanks!

**MWE**

https://www.overleaf.com/read/vppfdhtsgqyp

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{
    the name/.store in=\nodename,
    the name=OLD,
    my node/.style={
        node contents=\nodename,
        other node=\nodename,
    },
    other node/.style={
        append after command={
            \pgfextra
            \node [base right=of \tikzlastnode] {#1};
            \endpgfextra
        }
    }
}


\node (node 1) [
    the name=NEW, % temporary overrides the node name
    my node       % draw the nodes using the value stored in \nodename 
];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When TikZ processes a drawing command (any of `\draw`, `\path`, `\fill`, `\node`, etc) then it does so in a TeX group (and in a PGF scope, but it's the group that's key here) so any definitions are local only to that group.

The code from `append after command` is executed *outside* that group so is unaffected by any local definitions that were performed inside it.  There's a complicated smuggling routine since the contents of the `append after command` is defined *inside* the group that it is executed *outside* of.

To figure out what's going on in your code, we have to consider the question: When is `\nodename` expanded?

With your code then the result of the `append after command` is that TikZ remembers the following code to execute after the current command is finished (so, outside the group):

```
\pgfextra
\node [base right=of \tikzlastnode] {\nodename};
\endpgfextra
```

The important thing here is that the `#1` has been replaced just by `\nodename`.  When this is executed, and remember this is then *outside* the group, then `\nodename` is expanded to its value, which is now `OLD`.

To get the behaviour that you want we need to expand `\nodename` *inside* the group.  Fortunately, `pgfkeys` has handlers for this sort of situation, and it is easy enough to use.  Simply invoke the `other node` key with the `.expand once` handler:

```
other node/.expand once=\nodename,
```

With this version then the code that TikZ remembers is:

```
\pgfextra
\node [base right=of \tikzlastnode] {NEW};
\endpgfextra
```

and you get the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for the solution!